# Analog of cellular approximation theorem for $CW_0$-complexes ($CW_\mathcal P$-complexes)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, localization, rational-homotopy-theory

$CW_0$-complexes are analogs of $CW$-complexes, in which the "building blocks" are the rational disks $D^{n+1}_0$ whose boundaries are given by $\partial D^{n+1}_0= S^n_0$, where $S^n_0$ is a rationalization of the $n$-sphere. In partcular, $CW_0$-complexes are rational spaces. One can read more about this construction in [Hess - Rational homotopy theory: a brief introduction, Def 1.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604626.pdf) or in [FHT - Rational Homotopy Theory, Ch 9](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387950686).

Basically, a simply connected $CW_0$-complex $X$ is a space endowed by a filtration
$$ X(1)\subseteq X(2)\subseteq\cdots\subseteq X =\bigcup X(i)$$
such that there exists a pushout square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \bigsqcup_{j\in J_n} S^n_0 @>>> X(n)\\
    @V  V V @VV  V\\
    \bigsqcup_{j \in J_n}D^{n+1}_0 @>>> X(n+1)
\end{CD}

My question is if there is any analog of the cellular approximation theorem saying that a map $f\colon X\to Y$ between two $CW_0$-complexes is homotopic to to a map $f'$ that respects the filtration (i.e $f'(X(n))\subseteq Y(n)$).

This question makes also sense in a more general form. Given a set of primes $\mathcal P$, we may replace the $CW_0$-complexes by $CW_\mathcal P$-complexes, whose building blocks are $\mathcal P$-local disks (whose boundaries are $\mathcal P$-local spheres), etc, and ask the same question.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the functoriality of the rationalization/localization?

Comment: @user43326 If one starts by a map between the rationalizations $X_\mathbb Q\to Y_\mathbb Q$, it is not necessary that it is induced by a map $X\to Y$, so I don't think an answer will follow from the functoriality in an immediate way.

Comment: Well, it is not induced by a map $X\to Y$, but we can compose it to the map $X\to X _Q$ and get a map $X\to Y _Q$.  And, we have $(Y_Q)_Q=Y_Q$.

Comment: @user43326 Thanks! If yout turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: You are welcome.  But at a second thought,  can't we simply apply CW-approximation theorem to $CW_0$ complexes?

Comment: @user43326, I don't know if that is useful. If $X$ is a $CW_0$-complex, then we have that $X_k\subset X(k)\subset X_{k+1}$, where $X_i$ denotes the ordinary $i$-skeleton.

Comment: So at worst you get $f'(X(k))\subset Y(k+1)$, right?  I guess for most practical purpose this is good enough.